# hide all divs on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have 4 divs in my jsp page named **div1,2,3&4**.And I have to hide all these on page load.I got code for hiding a particular div.Bt want to hide all divs on page load. Please giv the code for hiding all the divs on page load.

Comment: Why ? Why don't you set them hidden using css ?

Comment: $('div').hide() done!!!

Comment: Don't forget to include `jquery` if you use @ricky 's method .

Comment: $('divid').hide(); its working....

Comment: @Ajmal, `$('div')` not `$('divid')` - this mean select all div

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `$('#divid').hide()` to hide the div on `document.ready()`.  `$('[id^="div"]')` selects all `div's` whose id starts with `div`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('[id^="div"]').hide();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Hello</div>
<div id="div2">Hello</div>
<div id="div3">Hello</div>
<div id="div4">Hello</div>
<div id="div5">Hello</div>
```

Comment: @Ajmal did you try it out as suggested. Please give a feedback

Answer (score 0):

There would be multiple approaches to this.

The first and in my opinion the best: use CSS.

```
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4{
display: none;
}
```

I would personally not use the javascript approach in this but that would be:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
     document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('div4').style.display = 'none';
 });
```

As mentioned above it is an option to use jQuery, but loading a complete library just for the purpose of hiding elements on page load...I would never advice you to do this unless you use jQuery elsewhere in your application (reused Shubham Khatri his code because it is the best way in jQuery)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('[id^="div"]').hide();
    })
```

Comment: You still gonna need to show them eventually I guess, so CSS solution to hide need a solution to show later . Well, i guess ;) Using JS could take the status in parameter.

Comment: Yes, I could add a .show class to it, but I dont think he is going to use the CSS approach in this and then you still would need javascript to append the class to the div.